# How to view SAML logout request and response on logout.jsp

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using latest version of Spring Security SAML to simulate an RP.
I need to view the SAML Logout Request and Response on the logout.jsp page.

It is easy to view auth request and response on a JSP page, but I am not sure how that works with the logout process.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to install addon SAML tracer for firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/